# Only producing two boxes in boxplot when my code has four boxes?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a boxplot with 4 boxes -- one with female control, one with male control, one with female experimental, and one with male experimental. I only get two boxes and I am not really sure why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
boxplot(dex$diff [dex$dexa <1] [dex$sex <1], dex$diff [dex$dexa <1] [dex$sex == 1], dex$diff [dex$dexa == 0] [dex$sex <1], dex$diff [dex$dexa == 0] [dex$sex > 0], xlab = "Control Dexa", ylab = "Weight Difference (Before - 6 Weeks) in kg", main = "Weight Loss Comparison Based on Sex", ylim = c(-10,10), col = "green")
```

[image]

There are two NA values in the sex column I dont know if that is what is causing the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use ggplot for this task. Here is an example I've created based on your information. For your next question, I recommend that you show at least a data.frame as an example of how your data is structured.

```
library(ggplot2)
data2use <- data.frame(female=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
                       exp=c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
                       diff=c(runif(25,0,10)))

    
data2use$group <- NA
data2use$group = ifelse(data2use$female==1 & data2use$exp==1, 1, data2use$group)
data2use$group = ifelse(data2use$female==1 & data2use$exp==0, 2, data2use$group)
data2use$group = ifelse(data2use$female==0 & data2use$exp==1, 3, data2use$group)
data2use$group = ifelse(data2use$female==0 & data2use$exp==0, 4, data2use$group)
    
data2use.long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data2use, cols=c("group"))
    
ggplot(data2use.long) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(x=value, y=diff, group=value), fill="forestgreen") +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: It is usually best to ask for clarifications from the OP before starting to wild-guess the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @GuedesBF. Actually, I think my example fits quite well due to the R-code she provides but in the future I'll pay more attention to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to plot a combination of your categorical columns, you can just use the formula interface with a "+" :

```
set.seed(199)
dex = data.frame(dex = rnorm(20,21),dexa = rbinom(20,1,0.5),sex = rbinom(20,1,0.5))

boxplot(dex ~ sex + dexa,data=dex)
```

[image]

If you have NAs, this still works:

```
dex$dexa[3:4] = NA
boxplot(dex ~ sex + dexa,data=dex)
```

[image]

I tried your code and could not get anything.